# Generate start date, end date and week numbers belong to given start and end date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want generate week no list and start date and end date for particular week by giving some date range and I did as using below formaula.But I want consider all dates after belong to week 52 as week 1.my formulas working well if start and end dates belong to same year.But if I select start date after 26th dec like my formulas doesnt work.Please help.I consider monday to sunday.If I select dec29 it shows incorrect data(red highlighted)
A1-Start date(this is giving by calender picker)
B1-End Date((this is giving by calender picker)

```
A3 =IF(A1="","",YEAR(A1))

B3 =IF($A$1-WEEKDAY($A$1,3) +((ROW()-3)*7) <= $B$1-WEEKDAY($B$1,3), ISOWEEKNUM($A$1-WEEKDAY($A$1,3)+((ROW()-3)*7)), "")

C3 =IF(DATE(YEAR(B1),MONTH(B1),DAY(B1))>=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),DAY(A1)),IF(A1<>"",A1,""),"CHECK DATE RANGE")

D3=IF(DATE(YEAR(B1),MONTH(B1),DAY(B1))>=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),DAY(A1)),IF(B1<>"",MIN(DATE(A3+1,1,2),(DATE(A3,1,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(A3,1,1),2)+B3*7)),""),"CHECK DATE RANGE")
```

[image]

I Want result as below

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Can you use the formula `=WEEKNUM($A$1)` in cell `B3` ?

Comment: It shows week 53.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These formulas will work in Row 3:

```
A3  =IF(ISNUMBER($A$1),YEAR(A1),"")
B3  =IF(ISNUMBER($A$1),WEEKNUM($A$1,2),"")
C3  =IF(ISNUMBER($A$1),$A$1-WEEKDAY($A$1,2)+1,"")
D3  =IF(ISNUMBER($A$1),$A$1+6-WEEKDAY($A$1,2)+1,"")
```

Starting in Row 4, enter these formulas, then use the auto-fill cursor (select cells A4:D4, then click and hold on the lower-right corner icon of the selection box) to copy-fill as many rows down as you need.

```
A4  =IF(ISNUMBER($D3),IF(($D3+1)<$B$1,YEAR($D3),""),"")
B4  =IF(ISNUMBER($D3),IF(($D3+1)<$B$1,WEEKNUM($D3,2),""),"")
C4  =IF(ISNUMBER($D3), IF( ($D3+1)<$B$1,  $D3+1,""),"")
D4  =IF(ISNUMBER($C4),$C4+6,"")
```

By the way, you mentioned in your post that you wanted Monday as the start of the week. So I used the value `2` in both `WEEKNUM` and `WEEKDAY`. Use a [different value](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/weeknum.php) for other days if needed.